# Как в Pandas DataFrame изменить элемент, избежав SettingWithCopyWarning?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

Считываю DataFrame из CSV, добавляю новый столбец, заполненный нулями и пытаюсь изменить отдельно взятый элемент в нем.

```
weather = pd.read_csv(path+"weather.csv");
weather["delay"]=0;
weather.iloc[0]["delay"]=1;
```

Но ничего не получается: элемент остается каким был и выводится:

> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:2:
>   SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
>   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `DataFrame.loc[]` / `DataFrame.iloc[]` / `DataFrame.at[]` / `DataFrame.iat[]` [индексеры](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html):

```
# создаем новый столбец заполненный нулями
weather["delay"] = 0

# присваиваем [1] по инексу [0] в столбце [delay]
weather.loc[0, "delay"] = 1
```

чтобы присвоить по порядковому номеру:

```
weather.loc[df.index[0], "delay"] = 1
```

> Что я делаю не так?

`weather.iloc[0]["delay"]` - это так называемый "chained indexing", в этом случае Pandas создаёт копию, которой вы пытаетесь присвоить данные.

PS как указанно в сообщении предупреждения [здесь](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing) можно подробно прочитать что происходит и как с этим бороться (на английском).

Comment: weather.loc[0, "delay"] = 1 - работает, weather.iloc[0, "delay"] и weather.loc[0]["delay"] - нет. А можно как-то по порядковому номеру, а не индексу?

Comment: `.loc[]` для *явной* индексации, `.iloc[]` (**i** значит **Integer**, целое число) для *позиционной* индексации. `0` (для первой строки) у вас вероятно и явное «имя» первой строки, и её позиция, но не так  `"delay"` - это не позиция (целое число).